# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype' error in pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

I have `categoryDf` which is spark Dataframe and its being printed successfully:

```
categoryDf.limit(10).toPandas()
```

[image]

I want to join this to another sparkdataframe. So, I tried this:

```
df1=spark.read.parquet("D:\\source\\202204121920-seller_central_opportunity_explorer_niche_summary.parquet")
#df1.limit(5).toPandas()

df2=df1.join(categoryDf,df1["category_id"] == categoryDf["cat_id"])
df2.show()
```

When I use `df2.show()` then I see the output as:

[image]

The join is happening succesfully.But when I tried to change it into `df2.limit(10).toPandas()`, I see the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype' error in pyspark
```

I want to see how the data looks after join. So, I tried to use `df2.limit(10).toPandas()`. Or is there any other method to see the data since my join is happening successfully?

My python version is:`3.7.7`

Spark version is:`2.4.4`

Comment: Can you post the full traceback message? DataFrames have a `dtypes` attribute. It would be interesting to see where exactly in the code the invalid reference happens.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem, in my case it was because I had duplicate column names after the join.

I see you have `report_date` and `marketplaceid` in both dataframes.  For each duplicated pair, you need to either drop one or both, or rename one of them.